# Display Json data in TextView without ListView

Tags: android, mysql, json

I need to display a total value of a query in mysql in my app using json.
A simple thing until I just think it does not find a solution, I always think tutorials that teach the list using a listview, but only need to display in simple TextView.

The PHP part is ready.

Can someone give me a way?

PHOTO: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIb9p.png)

Comment: Please include your code and the image of your current output in the question. Also, don't forget to include the some images of your expected output to help others answering this question.

Comment: @UmarZaii I put a print of the result.